# How to find the duration between dates?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I have the date as **07/24/2012** and the time as **23:59:59** in separate variables.  Using moment.js I am trying to find the number of days/hours/minutes between this and the current date.

How can this be done with moment.js?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `$date` holds "07/24/2012" and `$time` holds "23:59:59"...

```
moment($date + " " + $time, "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss").fromNow();
```

The `+` operator concatenates the strings which form a value that moment can parse directly.

Reference:

- [Moment parsing](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)
- [Moment time from now](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/)

Comment: I like this answer. Anyway, note that it's also possible to get a duration as [`moment.duration('23:59:59')`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/) (so just parse the date, and add the duration ..)

Comment: var dateNum = 07/24/2012;
var timeNum = 23:59:59;

var timeDura = moment(dateNum + " " + timeNum, "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss").fromNow();

alert(timeDura);

This is what I was doing, but it only gives me the days, no the hours and days.

Comment: The point here is you can construct a value that can be used by Moment  using the values you do have .. then you can do what you need.  If `fromNow()` isn't it, maybe you need [`duration()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/subtract/) instead, but the whole of Moment.JS is yours once you have a moment object.

Answer (score 1):

moment.js doesn't provide a "direct" way to perform this task as [`fromNow`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) likes to get clever and likes to use [`humanize`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/); however (using `from` in [the moment.js source](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/moment.js) as inspiration) we can derive [a little solution](http://jsfiddle.net/9Spt2/1/):

```
var whence = moment("2040-11-28")
var remaining = moment.duration(whence.diff(moment()))
```

Then to use/format the duration (sadly, there is no `duration.format()` available):

```
var r = remaining
var str = Math.floor(r.asDays()) + "." + r.hours() + ":" + r.minutes() + ":" + r.seconds()
alert(str)
```

PaulProgrammer's answer provides a nice solution on how how to get the date initially from the two separation values. Alternatively (since Moment.js 2.1.0), the date-time can be obtained through:

```
var whence = moment(yourDate, "MM/DD/YYYY").add(moment.duration(yourTimeOfDay))
```